# Keras: Embedding layer + LSTM: Time Dimension

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm

This might be too stupid to ask ... but ...

When using LSTM after the initial `Embedding` layer in Keras (for example the [Keras LSTM-IMDB tutorial code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py)), how does the `Embedding` layer know that there is a time dimension? In another word, how does the `Embedding layer know`the length of each sequence in the training data set? How does the Embedding layer know I am training on sentences, not on individual words? Does it simply infer during the training process?

Comment: Keras doesn't know, you do. How does an lstm know that what you are passing is a time series? You could train it on images and it wouldn't know, but you would... Not sure this is what you were  asking for though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Embedding` layer is usually either first or second layer of your model. If it's first (usually when you use `Sequential` API) - then you need to specify its input shape which is either `(seq_len,)` or `(None,)`. In a case when it's second layer (usually when you use `Functional` API) then you need to specify a first layer which is an `Input` layer. For this layer - you also need to specify shape. In a case when a shape is `(None,)` then an input shape is inferred from a size of a batch of data fed to a model.